# Is there a way to stop server from overwriting your HTML code?

Tags: php, html, apache, web

I run a website on dedicated Apache server of my friends. But the problem is, he runs an e-commerce on it too and have set-up that each page on the server upon retrieval gets added two  tags in the `head` for his own metrics by the server, which obviously messes up with `charset` declaration, that should come first in the `head`.

So the head of every page looks like this after server processes it:

```
<head>
<script></script>
<script></script>
<meta charset="utf-8>
</head>
```

Which is obviously bad from W3 validity standpoint and also int terms of those scripts blocking the page rendering until they are loaded, but he does not want to change this behavior.

So is there something I can do with my code so the server cannot alter the head?

Comment: "which obviously messes up with charset declaration, that should come first in the head." — No, it should come [within the first 1024 bytes of the document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#charset).

Comment: @Quentin From technical point of view, if you add the charset in the head on first line, it is the first 1024 bits (so we are both correct, only your are more technically accurate), but since those scripts are more than 1024 bits, the encoding gets fooked

Comment: Bytes, not bits … which makes them really rather long scripts.

Comment: Of course... the charset should primarily be denoted by a `Content-Type` HTTP response header... If that was set correctly by the server, this whole thing would be moot. It comes down to changing the server configuration either way.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to write HTML that a server can't modify between reading it into memory and sending it to a client.

Any means used to stop it being modified would depend entirely on how the software doing the modification works.

If it is applied via an Apache configuration directive then you might be able to turn it off with a different directive with a `<Location>`, `<Directory>` or other block that scopes it to just your files.

If it has some means for a file to exclude itself from the metrics (such as another `<meta>` directive, then you could use that.

Comment: So if I understand your suggestion correctly, I should implement my own .htaccess directive, that should be the second to overwrite the code since the directive directly from Apache config gets executed first and only then htaccess one, thus eliminating all the directives that come from the previous directives. Basically ask the apache to read the file again and rewrite it for me. That may work, but it will add some overhead to loading times

Comment: @TheLaw Apache has overhead due to htaccess anyway. But depending on the vhost config making directives may be blocked. Can't you ask him to move his metrics at the end of the head (before `</head>`)? That should work for you.